# Как сделать проверку латинских букв и символов через REGEX?

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

При написании кода нужно проверить строку на присутствие символов, а также латинских букв (a-z и A-Z). ps библиотеку re установил.

Пример:

```
a = 'apple1'
False

b = 'apple*'
True
```

Comment: интересно как вы устанавливали стандартную библиотеку `re`... ;)

Comment: я это написал наверняка, потому что на stack'e меня вовсе на 6 дней лишили вопросов задавать)))

Comment: "проверить строку на присутствие символов"... Кхм

Answer (score 1):

```
import re
import string

In [17]: pat = '^[a-zA-Z{}]+$'.format(re.escape(string.punctuation))

In [18]: bool(re.match(pat, 'apple1'))
Out[18]: False

In [19]: bool(re.match(pat, 'apple*'))
Out[19]: True
```